# Customize the error when using Google App engine standard Endpoint Security using API KEY

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, gcloud

I am building an API and using Google App engine standard environment, Java 8 runtime.

The REST api itself is built over guice + google endpoints apis.

I have configured the API Key based security for the endpoint as well. The issue I am facing is that when I provide an incorrect key, the service responds 400 Bad request with an HTML error payload.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <title>400 API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key</title>
</head>

<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
    <h1>Error: API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Is there a way to make the endpoint send a JSON message instead? I'd rather not burden the clients to parse HTML in some one-off cases.

Thanks

OpenAPI.json (Generated using :mvn endpoints-framework:openApiDocs )
Edited to remove sensitive info.

```
{
 "swagger": "2.0",
 "info": {
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "title": "my-app.appspot.com"
 },
 "host": "my-app.appspot.com",
 "basePath": "/_ah/api",
 "schemes": [
  "https"
 ],
 "consumes": [
  "application/json"
 ],
 "produces": [
  "application/json"
 ],
 "paths": {
  "/operation/v1/query/{type}": {
   "get": {
    "operationId": "Lookup",
    "parameters": [
     {
      "name": "type",
      "in": "path",
      "required": true,
      "type": "string"
     }
    ],
    "responses": {
     "200": {
      "description": "A successful response",
      "schema": {
       "$ref": "#/definitions/Result"
      }
     }
    },
    "security": [
     {
      "api_key": [ ]
     }
    ]
   }
  }
 },
 "securityDefinitions": {
  "api_key": {
   "type": "apiKey",
   "name": "key",
   "in": "query"
  }
 },
 "definitions": {
  "Result": {
   "type": "object",
   "properties": {

    "field1": {
     "type": "string"
    },
    "field2": {
     "type": "string"
    }
   }
  },
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi, GCP Endpoints does return a json response, for instance when following this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-compute-engine-docker) and passing a wrong api key using curl I do get a json response: {
 "code": 3,
 "message": "API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.",
 "details": [
  {
   "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.DebugInfo",
   "stackEntries": [],
   "detail": "service_control"
  }
 ]
}

Comment: ok i wonder if there is a difference between the compute engine vs App engine standard deployments?

Comment: In the yaml file you define the format to be used, for instance in the app engine endpoints [tutorial yaml file](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-app-engine-standard#endpoints_configure) is set as: "produces:     - application/json" for json format

Comment: yeah I got that in my json file.  "produces": [
  "application/json"
 ], It is rather strange.

Comment: could you please share your endpoints openapi.yaml (remember removing sensitive data and url's)

Comment: Just added the json.